# android:attach a image to contact

Tags: android, contacts

```
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/abc.jpg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, stream);   ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    int photoId = -1;
    Cursor cursor = c.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID
            + " = " + id, null, null);
    int idIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Photo.PHOTO_ID);
    System.out.println("cursor counts------------------"
            + cursor.getCount());

    System.out.println(Photo.PHOTO.equals(Photo.DATA15));

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        photoId = cursor.getInt(idIdx);
        System.out.print("photo id-------------" + photoId);
    }
    cursor.close();

    if (photoId > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("do update");
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(Data._ID + "=?", new String[]
                    { String.valueOf(photoId) })
                .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, id)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Photo.PHOTO, bytes).build());
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("do insert");
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, id)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Photo.PHOTO, bytes).build());
    }
    c.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

I used the codes above to insert or update a contact image, however, when I attached a image to a contact, the image only can be seen in the contacts list, if I go to the contact detail activity,I could not see the image.And sometimes the image will be attached to another contact instead of the specified contact(be specified by id).Any help is appreciated!:)

Answer (score 1):

At first ,thanks to your question,I figured out my problem by getting  some enlightenment from it.and my problem is that how to add picture to contact.I do it as follow

```
public void testInsert() {
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      Uri rawContactUri = this.getContext().getContentResolver()
                .insert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values);
      long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);
               //insert picture
      Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/abc.jpg");
      ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, stream);
      values.clear();
      values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
      values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
      values.put(Photo.PHOTO, stream.toByteArray());
      this.getContext()
                .getContentResolver()
                .insert(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                        values);
```

My English is not good enough to get all your words.And my codes can just insert the specified picture into the contact,hope it can help you.thanks you again,you problem helps me a lot.